# Is it possible to save output to file?

Tags: phpseclib

trying to use phpseclib.
I'm connecting to SSH (not unix server). Using command 'show onu info' to show all connected devices (it shows me MAC addresses)

All I want is to count how many devices are connected.
My idea is save output to txt file. Is it possible? Or is there any better way to count lines which include word "M0D9....."?

Thank you

```
code:
//phpseclib:
// myserver
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('myserverip');
$ssh->login('myusername', 'mypass') or die("Login failed");

echo $ssh->read('myusername@myserverip:~$');
$output = $ssh->write("show onu info\n");
echo $ssh->read('myusername@myserverip:~$');

echo "<br /><br /><br />";
```

Don't know what to do for counting.

### #

Tried str_word_count:

```
code:
//phpseclib:
// myserver
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('myserverip');
$ssh->login('myusername', 'mypass') or die("Login failed");

echo $ssh->read('myusername@myserverip:~$');
$str = $ssh->write("show onu info\n");
echo $ssh->read('myusername@myserverip:~$');

echo "<br /><br /><br />";
echo substr_count($str, "M0D9");
```

Didn't work. Still shows 0 but there are 15 M0D9 lines.

Comment: Can you please add your code what you tired, it will help to improve more readability and get help from others.

Comment: updated first post

Comment: Appreciate, Thanks for listening my comments

Comment: welcome. updated it again with more details

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just "pipe" the stdout of the machine to a text file like in the general unix case? Then in unix you can use grep to count number of occurences.
Could provide more information about the OS on server?

Comment: it's optical device (GPON Dasan). it doesn't know for example wc command

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
echo $ssh->read('myusername@myserverip:~$');
$str = $ssh->write("show onu info\n");
echo $ssh->read('myusername@myserverip:~$');

echo "<br /><br /><br />";
echo substr_count($str, "M0D9");
```

Try this instead:

```
echo $ssh->read('myusername@myserverip:~$');
$ssh->write("show onu info\n");
$output = $ssh->read('myusername@myserverip:~$');
echo $output;

echo "<br /><br /><br />";
echo substr_count($output, "M0D9");
```

Comment: thank you, seems it works fine. Any way to save counters into txt file?

Comment: @Renik - would `file_put_contents()` do what you're wanting?